# Javascript to check the age

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

How to write the Javascript,
 i.e., if user submits the form after fill the required blanks, Javascript should check for age from the current date i.e., if user is above 15 years then only form should submit, else they should alert the message  **"u r under 15"**.

Comment: What have you tried?  I hope you'll do better than "u r".  I wouldn't use any site that cared so little about their content.

Answer (score 2):

From the reference: http://jsperf.com/birthday-calculation

```
var age = calcAge(dateString);

function calcAge(dateString) {
  var birthday = +new Date(dateString);
  return ~~((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000));
}

// TODO Extra is:
if (age >= 15)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
    alert('You are under 15');
    return false
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YBzsG/3/)

Comment: the above funtion gives error in IE8.0 `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
var today = new Date();
var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
}
if(age < 15) {
    alert("You are under 15 age");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How does that check from the current date, as asked?  That checks an age value which is not being entered.

Comment: Ok understand....he edited his question...I will edit mine wait

Comment: Now see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Use
    document.forms[0].onsubmit=function()(
    return function_checkAge();
    )
Inside function_checkAge return true if age is correct and return false if age is incorrect ..
If false returned then form is not submitted.